# Are there good resources for creating a compelling motion graphics / interaction design for a website?

Tags: interaction-design, animation, landing-page, storyboard

There are several resources on how to simplify websites… that means know the purpose of the website and go straight to the point in a clear manner. Here are some examples (typically for web applications):

- http://mailchimp.com
- https://basecamp.com
- https://litmus.com

However, I haven’t found much resource on how to create / conceptualise compelling websites that has a ’story’ or engage users by its interactivity / animation. Here are some examples (typically for agency / portfolio / informational websites):

- http://creativecruise.nl
- http://www.fivefootsix.co.uk
- http://www.deutser.com

Are there any good resources that will help designers to conceptualise a compelling storyboard / motion graphics for the web without compromising user experience?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is opinion-based as the answer to this should be straight-forward references / materials?

Comment: are you looking for a resources or tools. the question isn't clear. It seems like you are looking for inspiration.